# Could EA know my password across multiple sites?

Tags: authentication

A few days ago I received an email from EA stating they reset my password because it *may* be compromised:

> The password for your Origin account was recently reset because a standard systems analysis indicated that your user name and password may have been subject to suspicious activity.  We have no reason to believe at this time that the suspicious activity is the result of unauthorised access to EA’s databases.  Instead, such activity could be related to issues with phishing, use of weak passwords, logging in from shared connections or even using the same password on multiple websites.  We apologise for any inconvenience this may cause you and hope you will recognise we’re taking this action to better protect your personal data.

This happened on the day that my Steam account was hacked and the user changed the email and password for Steam. My Steam account had no EA games on it, but they both used the same email and password.

In my mind that leaves two options of why my password was reset:

1. the Steam hacker tried to access my EA account with the same credentials but flagged something likely based on location of log in.
2. EA's "standard systems analysis" noticed I had used the same email and password and flagged it.

In my opinion it seems more likely it is #2 because it didn't appear anyone accessed my EA account, there were no signs I had an EA account from Steam, and the email states "using the same password on multiple websites" is a reason for changing.

If it is #2 like I believe it is how could EA possibly know I used the same password on both accounts without not only knowing my EA password but knowing my Steam password as well? If they couldn't know that why would they include that line in their email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are game related sites, therefore it makes sense that once one gets access to a steam account login and password, it will try it on related sites too, even if he is not sure about it.

What kind of evidence would you expect to find that someone got into tour EA account? EA claims to have blocked the suspicious activity, maybe based on geo location or other parameters as you suggested, and this email looks like the first sign that they gave you that something happened.

The text is pretty standard for this. They are not claiming that they are forcing you to change the password because of that, but that the suspicious activity they noticed may be becaus of that kind of thing, and reusing email is really one of the top common causes for it.

Comment: I have no evidence that they did not try to access my account just when they got into my Steam account they immediately changed my username, password, and changed my bio to "attacked by -name-", in EA nothing was changed or even attempted. It is very he did try to get in this account too and that's the reason it just seemed weird they included that info in their email.

Comment: Looks like EA suceesfully blocked the attack, then. No reason to believe they share login data.

Comment: Great! Looks like I just misread their intentions from their email